# Dropwizard attribute is not being stored in the session

Tags: dropwizard

I have a login screen on which i have a simple form with username and password fields. After successful login attempt I want to store user in the session and redirect to a home page.
loginUser method is part of LoginResource class

```
@POST
    public View loginUser(@FormParam("user") String username, @FormParam("pass") String password, @Context HttpServletRequest req) 
    {
        LoginService ls = new LoginService();
        User user = ls.login(username, password);
        if(user == null)
            return new LoginView();
        else
        {
            req.setAttribute("appUser", user);
            req.getSession().setAttribute("appUser", user);
            return new HomeView();
        }
    }
```

HomeView class:

```
public class HomeView extends View
{

    public HomeView()
    {
        super("home.ftl");
    }

}
```

Freemarker template home.ftl:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <#if appUser??>
            <h1>Welcome, ${appUser.username}!</h1>
        <#else>
            AppUser is not found in the session
        </#if>
    </body>
</html>
```

run() method of the class that extends Service:

```
@Override
    public void run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        //setting session handler
         environment.setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler());
         environment.addResource(new LoginResource());
   }
```

The problem is that when i make a successful login attempt it seems that my user is not saved in the session. Don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: Look into how the session is communicated from browser to application.   I.e. tomcat uses JSESSION cookie. It could be the user is getting a new session for each request. Sorry never use drop wizard before.

Comment: Session is not generated for each request, it seems that object is being saved in the session, but for some reason on a freemarker template page attributes are not available. I tried setting request attribute and session attribute.

Comment: I read article on how Spring integrates with Freemarker and it supports following config: <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true" />
    <property name="allowSessionOverride" value="true" /> It's interesting to know whether Dropwizard has similar config options available for Freemarker.

Comment: Okay. All the attributes are stored in the jetty http session, but there is a problem retrieving those attributes on the freemarker templates. Seems that Dropwizard is not pushing attributes from request and session scope to the Freemarker templates. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that you do not pass the object in session to the freemarker template: you have to pass User to the HomeView.

Please change your HomeView to

```
public class HomeView extends View
{
    private User user;

    public HomeView(User user)
    {
        super("home.ftl");
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

and reference it in your freemarker template as ${user.username}.

Hope it helps you out.

Bye,
Piero

Comment: Piero, thanks for your reply. 
If I'll do it the way you suggested, what will be the visibility scope of user variable? I want to store user value specifically in the session.

Comment: Hi, you will have "appUser" in session and user in the view... you are storing your variable in session and you can access it in the view.

Comment: How can I access it in the view? I don't want to pass User object as a view constructor parameter.

Comment: You cannot access it without passing it.

Comment: The FTL template needs a getter method to read the userName. You don't have to make your entire User object visible to the template if that matters to you; just make a 'getUserName' method, then you can refer to ${userName} in your template. In any case, Piero has the right answer.